# How to extend the number of the brushes?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to extend the number of colors in the `System.Windows.Media.Brushes` class, so I can do binding with the string name of the new Brush.

Like:  `value="myRed"`.

I use C#, .NET 4.5.2, VS2015, Windows 7.

Comment: I dont want to use a converter. I want to be able to use in multiple xaml files and in cs files.

Comment: So Basically you need `Extension Property` for a `Sealed Class`, which is in C# wish list?

Comment: Besides what Mike explains in his answer, you would not only have to extend the Brushes class, but also the code that converts from string to Brush. Taking a look at the .NET reference source (starting at BrushConverter) finally leads to an internal enum KnownColor and an internal class KnownColors with a giant nested switch statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible because the `System.Drawing.Brushes` class is `sealed`. This means it cannot be inherited from and therefore cannot be extended.

You are much better off creating a **Resource Dictionary** which contains your colours:

```
<ResourceDictionary ... >

    <!-- Declare your colours here. -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColour">#ffffff</SolidColorBrush>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And then include that dictionary in your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application ... >
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!-- You may need to include more than one resource dictionary. -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Your.Project;component/Path/To/Dictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

You can get to those resources in the code-behind like this:

```
Brush myColour = (Brush)Application.Current.FindResource("MyColour");
```

In my opinion this is a much better way that extending the existing `Brushes` class because there's a clear divide between what is *your* code, and what is the **.NET** code. Not only that, having your colours in a resource dictionary promotes reuse across projects and the resources can be easily extended and become more adaptive to changing requirements.

You can find out more about resource dictionaries in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references).